# Dash: Duplicate Callback Issue

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I am a newbie to python programming, facing following issue with dash app programming -

I am trying to create a dash app using basic callbacks. The callback runs fine for the first time after the app is activated but as soon as browser is refreshed or the callback function in the code is triggered again it shows the following error:

*"In the callback for output(s):
graph1.figure
Output 0 (graph1.figure) is already in use.
Any given output can only have one callback that sets it.
To resolve this situation, try combining these into
one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary."*

This is the code:

'''

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="graph1", figure={}), 
                       
                       dcc.Dropdown(id = "dropdown", options=[{'label':i, 'value':i} for i in df1['area']])])

@app.callback(
    Output('graph1', 'figure'), 
    Input('dropdown', 'value'))

def update1(rt):
    
    g = df[df['area']==rt]

    figg = px.bar(x = g['date'], y = g['Cases'])
    
    return figg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

'''

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: I have not added the dataframe in the code

Comment: Dash complains about `Output('graph1', 'figure')` being used in multiple callbacks. Isn't there any other callback in your code using this specific output ?

Comment: There is only once callback in the code. It runs fine the first time I run the code in jupyter notebook, this multiple callback error pops up only when the browser is refreshed or when the code is run again

Comment: Do you have any reason to use `app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])` instead of `app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])`? The problem you mentioned happened with me when using a jupyter notebook with separate cells for app creation and callbacks definition. If I update only the callbacks cell I started getting the errors you mentioned.